# How to exclude part of matching string from replacement?

Tags: sed

Let's say that I want to change all words ending with -et so that they instead end with -ert

Just doing a simple `sed 's/et /ert /g'` would work for all words followed by another word. But only if it is followed by a space. It can also be followed by '.', ',', ':' or other characters. Running `sed` for every individual case does not seem to be the correct way.

What I'm looking for is something like "for every match of AB, replace A with C, but don't touch B".

Clarification due to comments:

It's not limited to the ending of the words. I would like to do this inside words as well. Like:

```
$ echo "aaetxaa" | sed '?'
aaertxaa
$ echo "aaetyaa" | sed '?'
aaetyaa
```

So the replacement only took place when the matching ended with an x and not a y.

Comment: are you looking for word anchor? on GNU sed, this command `echo 'set meter' | sed 's/et\b/ert/g'` would give `sert meter`

Comment: @Sundeep I clarified the question

Comment: `t can also be followed by '.', ',', ':' ` ? So you want `s/et\([\.,: ]\)/ert\1/`? `or other characters.` - which characters? Any character? So you want `s/et\(.\)/ert\1/`? Just `s/et/ert/` then `for every match of AB, replace A with C, but don't touch B` - so `s/AB/CB/` or `s/A\(B\)/C\1/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to match `et` only if it is followed with `x` or end of string.

In this case, you may use

```
sed -E 's/et(x|$)/ert\1/g'
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/XvJrLX):

```
echo "aaetxaa" | sed -E 's/et(x|$)/ert\1/g'
# => aaertxaa
echo "aaetyaa" | sed -E 's/et(x|$)/ert\1/g'
# => aaetyaa
```

**Details**

- `-E` - POSIX ERE syntax enabled
- `s/` - substitution command, `/` is the delimiter
- `et(x|$)` - LHS: `et` followed with either `x` or end of string captured into Group 1
- `ert\1` - `ert` and the value of Group 1
- `g` - global flag: match and replace all occurrences on a line.

Comment: That's definitely what I was looking for. I was stuck in the thoughts of "ignoring" B during replacement phase, but just inserting B works just as fine. Thank you.